# Loading page in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, load

I want to have loading page screen. My app is the main component. There I have something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
   state = {isLoading: true}

   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchUser();
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
   }

   render() {
   if (this.state.isLoading) return <h1>Im loading the page</h1>;
   return (
      //MY MAIN PAGE
      );
   }
}
```

Seems like it doesnt work because 'im loading the page' text never apperas.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the `componentDidMount` is called immediately after component is mount, which sets the `isLoading` state to false. Therefore you never see the loading text. By looking at your code it seems like you want to show loading text while user is being fetched. In that case return a promise from the `fetchUser` function and resolve that promise when user is fetched and then set `isLoading` state to false like this

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.props.fetchUser().then(() => {
         this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems sounds here, I believe you just need to ditch the `if-else` for the ternary operator `?`. Per the [React docs](https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html):

> if-else statements don't work inside JSX. This is because JSX is just syntactic >sugar for function calls and object construction.

Try something like this in your `render()`:

```
render() {

  let component = this.state.isLoading ? <h1>I'm loading the page</h1> : // your app JSX;

  return component;
}
```

It also appears that you aren't initializing your `state` correctly. For React components written as stateful classes, you need to supply a `constructor()` function where you initialize `state`. Something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isLoading: true };
  }

  // rest of component code
  // your constructor should be written first
}
```

More information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor).

Comment: Prakash's answer also holds up. If you're setting the state to `false` immediately after the call to `fetchUsers()` has happened, the state is updating before the request actually returns. As he writes, wrapping it in a `Promise` is the correct way to handle that.

Comment: Check out my updated answer, the discussion of the `constructor` function and initializing `state` properly may be of some help.